# How to run a script in user mode inside an executable jar that is executed as root?

Tags: java, shell, raspberry-pi, vlc, runtime.exec

I want to run the following script within a Java executable jar on the Raspberry Pi.

the script (= stream.sh):

```
     #!/bin/sh
     raspivid -fps 25 -w 640 -h 360 -vf -n -o - -t 999999 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/cam.sdp,rtcp-mux}' :demux=h264
```

the Java code:

```
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh stream.sh"));
```

The problem is that the jar **must** be run with sudo and the vlc command doesn't accept sudo. Neither the script or the Java code contain sudo but as the jar is executed as sudo, vlc still gives the error "VLC is not supposed to be run as root...".

What is the easiest way to make the script run in user mode inside the jar?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `su -l $LOGIN -c $CMD` or `sudo -u $LOGIN $CMD`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo -u myuser sh stream.sh"));
```

man sudoers has all the information you need.

You need to change /etc/sudoers